# fc-match does not match bold correctly

Tags: fontconfig

For some reason `fc-match` does not like to match `bold` fonts:

```
$ fc-match monospace
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
$ fc-match monospace:bold
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
$ fc-match monospace:weight=200
DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Bold"
```

According to the documentation (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) `bold` and `weight=200` should be the same, but apparently they are not.

Some applications (especially Java) are using `monospace:bold` to find the bold monospace font, but they get the normal one which is then artificially emboldened, which looks very ugly.

Edit:
This only happens with fontconfig 2.13.0, which is used by Ubuntu 18.10. Earlier and later version used by 18.04 and 19.04 are fine.

Comment: Can you please share the output of `fc-list "DejaVu Sans Mono" file family style weight` ?

Comment: After some deep research I found that this is a bug in fontconfig 2.13.0 which is used by Ubuntu 18.10. Neither 2.12.6 used by 18.04 nor 2.13.1 which is apparently used in the upcoming 19.04 have that bug.

Comment: looks like `medium` is equivalent of `200`

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the questioner in [a comment to the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498019/fc-match-does-not-match-bold-correctly#comment928607_498019):

After some deep research I found that this is a bug in fontconfig 2.13.0 which is used by Ubuntu 18.10. Neither 2.12.6 used by 18.04 nor 2.13.1 which is apparently used in the upcoming 19.04 have that bug.